# Submitted double "10.03" becomes "1003". Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a field for entering a double value in a view. If I enter 10.03 , then on the server side I get 1003 and not 10.03. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you for your help!

Comment: This question needs code.  Please include the view code, the model code - and I strongly suggest you fire up Fiddler and take a look at the http traffic going to and from your browser

Comment: Your server side code has a locale settings that consider the decimal point as a thousands separator

Comment: Where is such a locale setting? I need to remove it asap ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have problems with localization. In some UI cultures dot is not a decimal mark.

Check your browser setting and culture on server

Comment: I'm on a managed server. Guess I can't change anything there. What to do then?

Comment: You can force locale in web.config or in global.asax. Here is a link: http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-set-locale-setting-in-c-web.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to check the  in the application's Web.config, if it is set to a different culture than EN-US , such culture dependent issue's may arrive.

You may use TryParse to get value in EN-US culture format.
for Help refer to 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d0a855c8-df12-433c-9342-ef12c2cfcc93